# Efficiency of std::iota in C++?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a vector:

```cpp
vector<int> v;
```

and I want it to be filled with the integers from 0 to 9. Then I have a couple options here:

```cpp
v.resize(10);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  v[i] = i;
}
// or
v.reserve(10);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  v.push_back(i);
}
// or
iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
```

Is there any memory/time advantage to using std::iota as opposed to the other two approaches? I personally find the former two more readable, although I may be conflating this with approachability since I am not an expert at C++ by any means.

Comment: The answer is always measure yourself.

Comment: `std::iota()` might (in the future) benefit from parallelization efforts of the standard library. I saw such things coming in C++ (where new hints can be used for e.g. `std::sort()` etc.)

Comment: @oblivion, "measure yourself" is fair (and I should start doing it more), but I've come across a lot of SO threads where the measurement is done very wrong. Being a beginner here, I'd rather learn from other people, especially since my use case is optimization.

Comment: @Richard I didn't mean to mean. There are many factors that must take into account e.g. OS, compiler, compiler flags...and at the end  you have to measure in your code otherwise you just have some hints not more.

Comment: In a quick test, GCC, Clang, and MSVC all reacted slightly differently to these, with the advantage going to any of the three methods depending on the compiler and on the length of the vector (hyper-vectorization as done by Clang for `iota` is a dead code path if you're only asking for 10 elements, but useful if you want a lot). So.. it depends?

Comment: My feeling is always use standard algorithms like `std::iota` because they can benefit from compiler tricks behind the scenes. Also I suspect `v.resize()` is faster than `v.reserve()` + `v.push_back()` because `v.push_back()` has to check the size every time in case of reallocation and `if` ranches kill performance.

Comment: @Galik there is a downside: with `iota` the compiler does not immediately see a constant-length loop. This confuses MSVC enough that it doesn't bother optimizing, and on the other hand confuses Clang into betting hard on the "huge vector" case (which is not the case we're in)

Comment: std::vector<int> v(10);
    std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), [i = 0] () mutable { return i++; });
    
    Linear or constant complexity.

Comment: Here is a link to a benchmark you can play with: https://quick-bench.com/q/I0gTx0vnJ5k5alrNlZOA85RFTK0

Answer (score 0):

There are many many potential solutions for the task.

But. there is a difference, between `push_back` and the other methods. `push_back` needs an empty `std::vector`, while others work on a `std::vector` with a given size.

Additionally. For 10 elements there will be only an insignificant delta in execution time. The calling overhead may take more time then iterating over the `std::vector` and assigning values.

Therefore, for a somehow reliable comparison, we should run the loop longer and more often.

The expectation is that `push_back` is the slowest function, because of internal checks for sufficient space.

The range based `for` loop, a loop based on `iterators`, `std::generate`and `std::iota` do all follow the same basic mechanism. Iteration and assignment.  They would also need an extra variable.

Multi-threading may help, but this depends on your system

Fastest should be a "normal" loop. And since it has the smallest footprint, I would recommend to use that.

But, you need to check on your system.

Please look at the following example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>
#include <future>
#include <array>
 
struct Timer {
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> startTime{};
    long long elapsedTime{};
    void start() { startTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); }
    void stop() { elapsedTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - startTime).count(); }
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Timer& t) { return os << t.elapsedTime << " ms "; }
};

constexpr std::size_t MaxSize = 50'000'000ull;
static constexpr std::size_t NumberOfThreads = 4;
static constexpr std::size_t BlockSize = 25;
static constexpr std::size_t MaxRepetition = NumberOfThreads * BlockSize;


int fillVector(std::vector<std::size_t>& v) {
    for (std::size_t k{}; k < BlockSize; ++k)
        for (std::size_t i{}; i < MaxSize; ++i)
            v[i] = i;
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    Timer t{};
    {
        std::vector<std::size_t> v{};
        v.reserve(MaxSize);

        t.start();
        for (std::size_t r{}; r < MaxRepetition; ++r) {
            for (std::size_t i{}; i < MaxSize; ++i)
                v.push_back(i);
            v.clear();
        }
        t.stop(); std::cout << "push_back:\t\t " << t << '\n';
    }
    {
        std::vector<std::size_t> v(MaxSize);


        t.start();
        for (std::size_t r{}; r < MaxRepetition; ++r)
            for (std::size_t i{}; i < MaxSize; ++i)
                v[i] = i;
        t.stop(); std::cout << "Standard loop:\t\t " << t << '\n';

        t.start();
        for (std::size_t r{}; r < MaxRepetition; ++r)
            for (std::size_t i{}; std::size_t & vi : v) vi = i++;
        t.stop(); std::cout << "range based for loop:\t " << t << '\n';

        std::size_t k{};
        t.start();
        for (std::size_t r{}; r < MaxRepetition; ++r) {
            k = 0;
            for (auto i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i)
                *i = k++;
        }
        t.stop(); std::cout << "with iterators:\t\t " << t << '\n';

        t.start();
        for (std::size_t r{}; r < MaxRepetition; ++r)
            std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), [i = 0ull]() mutable { return i++; });
        t.stop(); std::cout << "std::generate:\t\t " << t << '\n';

        t.start();
        for (std::size_t r{}; r < MaxRepetition; ++r)
            std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
        t.stop(); std::cout << "std::iota:    \t\t " << t << '\n';

        t.start();
        std::array<std::shared_future<int>, NumberOfThreads> dummy{};
        for (std::size_t threadNumber{}; threadNumber < NumberOfThreads; ++threadNumber) {
            dummy[threadNumber] = std::async(fillVector, std::ref(v));
        }
        for (unsigned int threadNumber{}; threadNumber < NumberOfThreads; ++threadNumber) {
            dummy[threadNumber].wait();
        }
        t.stop(); std::cout << "std::async:  \t\t " << t << '\n';
    }
}
```

This produces the following output on my Windows 7 machine from 2012

```
push_back:               8805 ms
Standard loop:           1441 ms
range based for loop:    3394 ms
with iterators:          3397 ms
std::generate:           3409 ms
std::iota:               3402 ms
std::async:              1499 ms
```

Multi-threading for such a small function does maybe not make that much sense.

Time measurement with chrono-functions may also not be as accurate as expected.

Comment: Could you please add informations about how you have compiled this code? Were optimizations enabled?

Comment: Seems like this will also be processor dependent. i7 -- it's a wash, not much difference at all. AMD, significant saving for `async` (unless it just used cached results like `Standard loop` did). (gcc 12.2.1, `-Ofast` optimization, `-std=c++17`)

Comment: Compiled in "Release Mode", all speed optimizations on